# Preston Garvey won't talk to me

Tags: fallout-4

After completing **The First Step**, Preston Garvey will no longer talk to me. If I walk up to him, I see the option to press <kbd>E</kbd> to initiate a talk but pushing <kbd>E</kbd> doesn't do anything. Is there anyway I can reset him so that I can talk to him again?

Comment: I'm not going to post this an answer right now because I don't really think this fixes the issue but I was able to talk to him again after completing `Sanctuary`

Comment: I think @wawa may be right. I remember him not talking to me for awhile, and then resuming after I made some quest progress.

Comment: Agreed, I had the same issue. Once I completed Sanctuary I was able to talk to him and continue. I also may have saved/quit/restarted at some point too just coincidentally if that's worth a shot.

Comment: @TimS. I tried saving/quitting/restarting to no avail. I even tried console commands to reset the npc which also didn't work. Maybe you can't talk to him until `Sanctuary` is complete? If anyone else sees the same behavior, I'll post that as an answer.

Comment: I know I had Sanctuary complete before he would talk, it just happened that I restarted within that time too. Try completing the quest first, as you mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

Try completing the quest **Sanctuary**. I was able to talk to him again after that.

Comment: I'll double-check next time I'm in-game, but I'm pretty sure I'm done with Sanctuary. Sturges has been telling me for awhile that Preston wants to talk, but he still isn't engaging.

Comment: @Iszi, make sure you've built Mama Murphy's chair or Preston won't talk to you, even if Sturges says he wants to.

Answer (score 0):

He seems to break when he leaves to go gather men at the castle, as I have found out before starting this mission.

Make sure he isn't following you, then after the you beat the Queen Lurker and fix the radio he will follow you. You will have to load back to fix him.

Comment: Hi, this happened quite a bit before that mission. Funny enough, I actually had him as my companion when he took off to go to the castle. I just ended up following him anyway.