# Preston Garvey won't talk to me at Sanctuary Hills!

Tags: fallout-4

I have finished the Sanctuary quest to provide food, beds, clean water, and defenses. After all of that is done Sturges tells me that Preston wants to talk. Whenever I try to talk to Preston he just looks at me and gives me a short quote like, thank god it's not raining. I really need help with this because I know he is needed for future quests. I also know he is a companion that can tag along with you. Someone please help!

Comment: Consider yourself lucky....he never shuts up when I go near him....

Comment: But @Dupree3, another settlement needs our help!

Comment: @DangerZone there are only so many times I can help the same person with the same problem, in the same location, and killing the same enemies.....before i just tell the settlement to go away lol

Comment: possible duplicate: [Preston Garvey won't talk to me](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/242854/108003)

Comment: Pretty sure I had this, and I just dicked around in side thigs for awhile. He let me continue when I came back.

Comment: What does your quest log tell you to do?

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per DCShannon's comment.

Answer (score 2):

This is very similar to a known bug listed on Preston Garvey's [wiki page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Preston_Garvey). There are some fixes listed there too that may help to resolve the issue.

From the site:

> PC - This can be fixed on PC by opening the console, selecting Preston
>   Garvey and inputting removefac 00075d56.
>
> XboxOne - A possible fix for this is to have Preston as a companion
>   while initiating the assault on the Castle.
>
> XboxOne - Another possible fix is if the Sole Survivor sides with The
>   Minutemen against The Institute in the endgame. After activating the
>   bomb in The Nuclear Option, Preston will talk and can be asked to
>   follow the Sole Survivor. [verification needed]
>
> XboxOne - Another possible fix is if you attach a generator to the
>   conduits and wires already setup in the castle the power requirements
>   will turn green in the workshop menu and he will be able to act
>   normally again. [verified]

Comment: That doesn't look like the same bug necessarily... OP never mentions the quest to reclaim the Castle and appears to be on a much earlier quest. (Setting up Sanctuary should typically happen a bit earlier than claiming the Castle).

Comment: @DangerZone Maybe, but it has identical symptoms, and if OP is on PC, the same command may work to fix this. Or, maybe all it takes is OP getting to the point where they control the Castle. Either way, it's a possible solution.

Comment: True, but you may want to note that it's a *nearly* identical situation and the solutions *may* fix the problem. Current language implies that it is exactly the same and the fixes will work.

Comment: @DangerZone Good point. I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: I am playing Fallout 4 on an Xbox One and it is after you set up Sanctuary and it wont let me engage in a conversation with him at all. I don't even know where the castle is.

Comment: @EclipseInDark The Castle is a settlement you get in a later quest. Does your quest log tell you to talk to Preston?

Comment: my quest log dosent tell me to talk to preston

Comment: @EclipseInDark I would guess that maybe you're not supposed to talk to Preston yet. Try finishing a couple more quests.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem for a while, if I remember correctly he wouldn't talk to me until I built Mama Murphy's chair. Check your quest log in the Pip-Boy, it should tell you if there's still something you need to do. If the problem is Mama Murphy's chair, you can find it in the workshop menu (under Special) and you need to build it to proceed with the quest. After I'd built her chair I could have the conversation with Preston to complete the quest.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Sturges said the same to me, over and over.  I found that once you complete some of the Minuteman quests then he will speak to you.  You can tell when he or others are ready to talk when the little yellow balloon is displayed over their heads.  This means that a character has something to say and usually opens up other quests/missions in the game. So just keep playing and the issue gets resolved. Hope that helps :)

Answer (score 0):

I sided with the Minutemen for my end faction on the PS4. Immediately after completing the Nuclear Option I was able to access his dialogue wheel and put him in my party.

Comment: So you managed to finish the game with the Minutemen despite Preston refusing to talk with you since settling Sanctuary?

Answer (score 0):

I'm playing on PS4 and he would not talk to me but then I hit him in the back with a machete he started talking to me again, I'm not sure why this worked but it did and I dont know if its a 100% chance to fix it.