# Can Preston Garvey's perk still be obtained if he cannot be your companion?

Tags: fallout-4

I've unfortunately fallen into the glitch scenario with Preston Garvey, described in a [few](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242854/preston-garvey-wont-talk-to-me) [other](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/243825/preston-stops-following-me-after-retaking-the-castle/245597#245597) [questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/249867/preston-garvey-wont-talk-to-me-at-sanctuary-hills), where dialogue can't be initiated, and therefore he cannot be my companion. I don't have any viable pre-Castle mission saves to revert back to.

However, I've noticed that if he is nearby when doing weapon modifications, I'll still see a "Preston liked that" notification, so I'm seemingly still gaining affection with him. Doing this enough times **should** max out affection, so would his perk be obtainable in this glitched state? Perhaps by:

1. Obtaining it when his affinity maxes out, even though he is not my active companion, without the need to have the 'idolized' affinity conversation?
2. Allowing an affinity dialog to occur between affinity levels, even though all other dialog is not working with him?

Can you get Preston Garvey's perk, even if he is dialog-glitched and cannot become your companion?

Comment: On the PC you can use the console to add it

Comment: @z' Yeah, I almost added a console tag (ps4, btw) to signify that I didn't have console access to fix Preston or simply add the perk myself, but ended up not doing so. I know on Meta at one point there was a discussion about whether adding console tags to let users know what kind of answers would be helpful/doable was alright, but I couldn't find it.

Comment: @king14nyr You might be thinking of [this meta](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/5488/questions-where-op-has-mentioned-he-she-is-using-a-specific-platform-how-to-ans), the gist of which is: General questions/answers are always preferable. Someone could have the same question for PC and *not* having the console solution would be unhelpful for those people.

Comment: @MrLemon that's the one, thanks. I didn't tag it with any platform because I didn't want to exclude/discourage PC answers with console commands, those could probably be useful to others down the line. Ideally, the perfect answer would have console commands to fix it on PC, and an answer one way or the other (if the perk is obtainable) for those on Xbone and PS4 as well.

Comment: Half of the solution would be (for PC players): open console and enter `player.addperk 00084298`

Answer (score 2):

No he can't. Preston must be your active companion. Only then he can talk to you about your relationship.
You still can get notifications like:

"Preston tolerates you"

"Preston admires you"

"Preston idolizes you"

But affection events are triggered only when character is your active companion.

---

For PC players, you can try console command to make target your companion:

```
setplayerteammate 1
```